# solving a simple problem of combination , with different approach

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I found a question and I have different approach to solve it , but unable to get the answer.

Question :How many 3-digit numbers can be formed from the digits 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 and 9, which are divisible by 5 and none of the digits is repeated?

I solve it like this :

divisible by 5 : means I have to put '5' at unit digit.

now I have 5 numbers left(excluding '5') , and have to choose 2 of them.

I just learn permutation and combination and found that this is the example of permutation.(reason : 21 is not equal to 12).

so `5P2 ways to solve this. which makes my answer to 5*4*3=60.

their solution :

divisible by 5 : means I have to put '5' at unit digit.

The tens place can now be filled by any of the remaining 5 digits (2, 3, 6, 7, 9). So, there are 5 ways of filling the tens place.

The hundreds place can now be filled by any of the remaining 4 digits. So, there are 4 ways of filling it.

so the answer is going to be 5*4=20

please tell me where I am missing. any topic name or link to the tutorial is welcomed.

Comment: You just calculated $_5P_2$ incorrectly: it’s $5\cdot 4$, not $5\cdot 4\cdot 3$. The reason is exactly the argument that they gave: there are $5$ ways to choose the first digit, and each of those can be combined with any of $4$ possible second digits.

Comment: When you have more numbers than positions and want to know all possible permutations with no repetition is the case of _variations_, what is a falling factorial of the amount of possible different values to a number of position, in your case is $(5)_2=5\cdot 4=20$.

Answer (score 1):

So there are 3 digits right? Consider the number be called:

$u = xyz$ where $xyz$ are just digits (Not multiplied)

You know $u$ is divisible by 5 therefore $z = 5$ is certain. No numbers can be repeated.

Total = 6 numbers.
Because $z = 5$, total left = 5 numbers.

$u = xy5$

There are 5 remaining possibilities of $y$
There are now 4 remaining possibilities of $x$
There is ONE (1) possibility of $z$
$u = xy5$

Total Possibilities: (5)(4)(1) = 20 possibilities.